# Spring Boot добавить в classpath внешний jar

Tags: maven, spring-boot

Казалось-бы простая задача. В гугле достаточно ресурсов на эту тему, но у меня не получается...

У меня есть основной main.jar проект.

И есть дополнительное приложение add.jar, которое должно использоваться в основном проекте.

Оба приложения Spring Boot с Maven.

Я пытаюсь запустить:

```
java \
-cp /path/to/main.jar:/path/to/add.jar \
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev \
 org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

Проект запускается, но контейнер спринга не подгружает бины из add.jar

В обоих проектах есть Main.class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Приложение Main.jar содержит MANIFEST

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven Archiver 3.4.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 11
Implementation-Title: main
Implementation-Version: 1.0.0
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
Start-Class: ru.testing.Main
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.2.0.RELEASE
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
```

Приложение add.jar содержит MANIFEST

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven Archiver 3.4.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 11
Implementation-Title: add
Implementation-Version: 1.0.0
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: ru.testing.additional.Main
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.2.0.RELEASE
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
```

Comment: а добавить add.jar в зависимости Main.jar никак?

Comment: нет, у меня задача стоит, чтоб именно таким путем

Comment: тогда, думаю стоит указать через аннотацию @ComponentScan в основном приложении пакеты, в которых стоит поискать бины.

Comment: @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "ru") - пробовал, не помогает...

Comment: add.jar не попадает в контейнер спринга main.jar

Answer (score 0):

Надо вот так

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"ru.testing.additional"}
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Иными словами, пакеты в `scanBasePackages` сканируются неркурсивно, поэтому `"ru"` не работает.

Если в основном jar не хочется упоминать дополнительные пакеты, то в add.jar можно создать точку входа, доступную по известному пути в основном jar-е

```
package ru.testing; // этот путь известен в main.jar

@Configuration 
@ComponentScan(... тут указать пакеты из add.jar ...)
public class AddJarScanConfiguration {}
```